# Maven deploying a specific artifact

Tags: java, maven, obfuscation

So I am working with the Proguard Plugin to obfuscate one of my jars before deploying it to Maven. My goal is to have only the obfuscated jar deployed to Maven.

Currently I noticed that two jars get deployed, myJar.jar and myJar-small.jar (the obfuscated one from proguard). I have confimed that my Nexus index contains both of them and a single pom after being deployed. The problem is that when I add myJar as a maven dependency to another project, the unobfuscated jar is pulled into the project, not the obfuscated jar.

Is there way to only upload the obfuscated jar or to specify which jar should be pulled into other projects?

I have looked at the Proguard options [here](http://pyx4me.com/pyx4me-maven-plugins/proguard-maven-plugin/proguard-mojo.html), but not been able to find much that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your own use, when you define your dependency, add the classifier tag with a value of small.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>myJar</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <classifier>small</classifier> <!-- <<<<<< like this <<<<<< -->
</dependency>
```

For publishing, you can manually deploy the artifact with a new classifier as demonstrated here:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploying-with-classifiers.html

Answer (score 3):

I assume you use the Maven ProGaurd Plugin (http://pyx4me.com/pyx4me-maven-plugins/proguard-maven-plugin).

If you leave the `attach` parameter on its default `false` value and do not set anything for `outjar`, the original artifact is overriden by the obfuscated one. Thus, only the obfuscated version will be deployed.

Comment: it is creating an additional jar with the name <jarname>_small.jar